# Image does not touch the edges, Android

Tags: android

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFEBEE"
    tools:context="com.alertavecino.alertavecino.MainActivity">

    <!--<Button
        android:text="@string/alerta_ladron"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnAlertaLadron"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videoPreviewImage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnEmergenciaSalud"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnEmergenciaSalud" />-->

    <com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary.widget.AdjustableImageView
        android:id="@+id/videoPreviewImage"
        android:background="@drawable/cruz_roja"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ambulancia_imagen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/emergencia_salud"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shadow"
        android:id="@+id/btnEmergenciaSalud"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoPreviewImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:onClick="start_salud"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The Image here is `com.inthecheesefactory.thecheeselibrary.widget.AdjustableImageView`, it is a trick to be able to use **adjustViewBounds** in a **API level lower than 18**.

Is this the correct way to implement **adjustViewBounds** to lower API levels?

[image: description of the problem]

---

**Why does the image doesn't touch the edges?**

Comment: Look at the `padding*` attributes on the root `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Yep, It was that the problem. Post it as an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: I'll just mark this as a duplicate of a similar question. Thanks, though. Cheers!